# High Volume Portal User Custom Field on Formula Field

Tags: customer-portal, formula, custom-field, custom-object, user-record

I have created a custom field on the User Object - Canvas_Id__c ... This value is only populated when the user is a high volume portal seat user.

I have a custom object Student Task where I want to insert this using a custom field.  I created a new field and pick formula then I go to the Advanced Formula tab and insert field.

Student Task > Student > Portal User > Canvas Id and It generated:

Student__r.Portal_User__r.Canvas_ID__c

When I go to view the page it shows up blank.  I am logged in as System Admin.

Any thoughts on why this would show blank even though I can clearly see the data on the User Record?

Answer (score 4):

My initial thought would be to check Field Level Security. Just because you are an admin doesn't mean you have the proper field level security for all of those fields. It still needs to be enabled for the field for the System Administrator profile to view.

Outside of that, this should work. I quickly tested it in a development org and I was able to properly set up a field on the User object and then get that field to display on a test object through a formula field and a lookup relationship.

**EDIT:** After reviewing the information below from Brian, it sounds like this is not possible as a formula. As such, I would like to suggest some alternatives.

The most obvious solution would be to move this field to the Student object (assuming the Student to User is a 1-to-1 relationship). You will definitely be able to access the field via a formula this way.

The other solution would be to create a trigger on the User object and handle updating a readonly field on the Student Task object whenever the User Canvas_Id__c field is changed (i.e., after insert && after update). This should keep the two values in sync.

Comment: David asked: "The field Canvas_ID has the proper FLS and should be visible for us to see. When you performed your Test, was the Contact tied to a High Volume Portal seat vs. a Customer Portal Seat?"

Comment: No, this specific user was not set up as a high volume customer portal user. I would assume this wouldn't matter as the data model should be viewing this as just a User object (which has always been the case in my experience). Let me see if I can get the portal set up and try it out.

Comment: Tier 1 Support went to Tier 2 at SFDC and they said it is not possible with the Portal User.  Our thought is it shouldn't show up in the pick lists then.

Comment: Very interesting. I would have assumed it was possible to do with any User object. I don't know why that would matter.

Comment: I agree.  We have someone a little higher up the food chain at SFDC we are going to ask as well.  Might just be a bug.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Sometimes it isn't a bad idea to go higher up the chain. There are certain limitations to the portal, but I didn't think it extended to this extent. Either way, I updated my answer with some alternatives for you if you can't get this worked out.